# PHP MySQL system call creates empty file, has no return val, and produces no error message

Tags: php, mysql, command, system

I've burned more hours than I care to admit trying to figure this out :)  A file is created successfully, however it is either 0 bytes or includes the mysql man page.  I cant seem to get this to execute correctly or get an error message out.

The query executes correctly in MySQLAdmin. I can replace the mysql call with ls and it pipes a listing of the files into my output file. The host, user, and password strings are all correct and formatted well.  Leads me to believe there is something wrong with my syntax?

```
$command = 'mysql --host=localhost --user='.DBASEUSER.' --password='.DBASEBPSWD.' --database='.DBASE.' -execute=SELECT Real_acct.Mail_Addr_1 from Real_acct > ../outputfiles/output.txt';
$returnVal = system($command, $returnVal);
```

Answer (score 1):

You only have one dash (`-`) before your `execute` parameter. You would probably also need double quotes around your query statement:

```
$command = 'mysql --host=localhost --user='.DBASEUSER
    .' --password='.DBASEBPSWD
    .' --database='.DBASE
    .' --execute="SELECT Real_acct.Mail_Addr_1 from Real_acct" > ../outputfiles/output.txt';
$returnVal = system($command, $returnVal);
```